# Python selenium webdriver: retrieving google reviews based on the date

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium webdriver to extract google reviews of an app from google play store. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

driver = webdriver.Chrome('path')
baseurl = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapmyrun.android2&showAllReviews=true'
driver.get(baseurl)

counter = 0
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(2)
    counter = counter + 1
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[text()='Show More']"))>0:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Show More')]").click()
        counter = 0
    if counter == 10:
        element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='LXrl4c']")
        break;
names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='bAhLNe kx8XBd']//span[@class='X43Kjb']")
person_info = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='d15Mdf bAhLNe']")


for count, person in enumerate(person_info):
    review_response_person = ''
    response_date = ''
    response_text = ''
    full_text = ''
    
    name = person.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='X43Kjb']").text
    review = person.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='UD7Dzf']/span").text
    review_date = person.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='p2TkOb']").text
    rating = person.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='pf5lIe']/div").get_attribute('aria-label')
    useful = person.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='XlMhZe']//div[@aria-label='Number of times this review was rated helpful']").text
    reviewText = person.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[jsname='fbQN7e']")
    full_text = reviewText.get_attribute("innerHTML")
    
    if len(full_text) > 1:
        review = full_text
    
    if person.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='LVQB0b']"):
        review_response_person = person.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='LVQB0b']//div/span[@class='X43Kjb']").text
        response_date = person.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='LVQB0b']//div/span[@class='p2TkOb']").text
        response_text = person.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='LVQB0b']").text
        response_text = response_text.replace(review_response_person, '')
        response_text = response_text.replace(response_date, '')
```

The problem is that I want to extract reviews w.r.t to date range. For instance, I want to extract reviews that are posted only today or tomorrow. I tried to find any method in selenium webdriver but could not find it. Could anyone guide me if we can retrieve the reviews based on date?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a condition to get the data, something like:

```
today_data=[] 
for count, person in enumerate(person_info):
    review_date = person.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='p2TkOb']").text.lower()
    review_date=dt.datetime.strptime(review_date,"%d %B %Y")
    name = person.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='X43Kjb']").text
    review = person.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='UD7Dzf']/span").text
    if review_date > dt.datetime(year=2021,month=1,day=23):
        today_data.append(name)
        today_data.append(review)
```

Then, you would have the name and review between the 23/01/2021 and today, for instance.

If you have are located in a specific country, change the timezone to your specific country, in order to have no error in the interpretation of "%B":

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.UTF-8')
```